# Could anyone create a tag called "program-like"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Could anyone create a tag called "program-like"? It would be for questions that try to find a programs with the defined features (It´s a way I used to use this website, I define the features of an ideal program I need and then I answer for it in this page, because there is a great probability that my ideal program or some like it has already be done) , or questions that try to find alternatives programs to other programs (for instance for looking for free alternatives to popular programs). Thank you so much!

Examples of questions for I would like to use it:

[Looking for a program that stores the images from the clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/536287/looking-for-a-program-that-stores-the-images-from-the-clipboard)

[Free alternative to Catia, SolidWorks](https://superuser.com/questions/280147/free-alternative-to-catia-solidworks)

[Looking for a program to create test and do exams](https://superuser.com/questions/364252/looking-for-a-program-to-create-test-and-do-exams)

[Extractor Information program by detecting syntactic patterns](https://superuser.com/questions/281959/extractor-information-program-by-detecting-syntactic-patterns)

[Program to synchronize folders between my PC and mobile by bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/261888/program-to-synchronize-folders-between-my-pc-and-mobile-by-bluetooth)

[Recommendation for a good image format conversion program](https://superuser.com/questions/227009/recommendation-for-a-good-image-format-conversion-program)

[I'm looking for a program that can automate opening/closing a program](https://superuser.com/questions/239345/im-looking-for-a-program-that-can-automate-opening-closing-a-program)

[Program to convert a laptop in a USB storage](https://superuser.com/questions/237717/program-to-convert-a-laptop-in-a-usb-storage)

Comment: Check out http://alternativeto.net/...

Comment: @Breakthrough: By the way, do you know any website, with the same philosophy but for websites recomendations instead of software recomendations?

Comment: Actually, there's a lot of websites already in the AlternativeTO database, but that's just a starting trend.  I also found [http://www.similarsites.com/](http://www.similarsites.com/)...

Comment: Oh thank so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the existing [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) and [its information](https://superuser.com/tags/software-rec/info).

Comment: Two notes here: 1) The tag itself is a meta tag and I'm not sure if at that point we should keep it 2) I updated the tag wiki to add a little more info about this—basically, once we can get our FAQ changes through, product recommendations would be considered off topic anyway.